# Нужно упорядочить массив по убыванию квадратов элементов. Python

Tags: python

Допустим есть массив A=[-2,3,-5,4,0]
Мне нужно чтоб он упорядочился как [-5,4,3,-2,0]

Comment: Что у вас не получилось?

Answer (score 1):

[Метод `List.sort` в Python](https://dev-gang.ru/article/metod-listsort-v-python-b5gidv4ync/)

```py
def sq(n):
    return n * n

lst = [-2,3,-5,4,0]
lst.sort(key = sq, reverse = True)
print(lst)

# -> [-5, 4, 3, -2, 0]
```